Create a download link for generated CSV file in flask
I have a Python web application where user upload an image and the code is generating a CSV from that image. What i need is to return that csv to app.py and display it on the frontend for user to download it. How i achieve that?
app.py
# Route to show processed files
@app.route('/view_process', endpoint='view_process')
def process_files():
    
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return redirect(url_for('login_user'))
    
    subprocess.run(['python', 'inference.py'])

    return render_template('view_process.html', message='Files processed sucessfully')

Inference.py
from utils import *

processInputs(cfg, outputs, im_bgr_list, output_directory, im_names)

Utils.py
def processInputs(cfg, outputs, im_bgr_list, output_directory, im_names):
    
  getSegmentationCsv(outputs[i],im_bgr_list[i],im_names[i],output_directory)

def getSegmentationCsv(output,im_bgr,im_name, output_dir):
 df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
    
    # Give the filename you wish to save the file to
    filename = output_dir+im_name.split('.')[0] + '.csv'

    # Use this function to search for any files which match your filename
    files_present = glob.glob(filename)


    # if no matching files, write to csv, if there are matching files, print statement
    if not files_present:
        df.to_csv(filename, index = False)


You have to use GET/POST requests to do so. You can either use the basic HTTP request, which will reload the whole page, or you can use ajax, to reload only certain parts of the page.
If you use the POST method you have to add methods=[GET,POST] attribute to @app.route('/view_process', endpoint='view_process')
In your return statement, I see that you are passing an attribute message, and I am assuming that the message is received by the front-end. Assuming that you are using Java Script to receive the message, you can pass another argument, such as path="filepath.csv", and add a <a download></a> tag to the front-end, and dynamically change the href attribute to the received file path, in this case, path.
Make sure that you modify utils.py and inference.py to return the filename to app.py

Sounds great! Can you provide an example on how to do that?
